# Most common way of storing Data in Swift5 in Combination with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, userdefaults

I am about to begin with a new project and now have the choice between several Data Persistence Frameworks. Until now I used to store my JSON Arrays in UserDefaults, but I have read, that this is no good practice for bigger data.

I basically heard of two methods: 
1. Storing Data with CoreData 
2. Storing Data as File in Document Folder of Apps Container

The Data to be stored are objects with +-10 fields consisting of Strings, Dates, Booleans and Images.

What would be the best practice to make these files persistent and eventually even accessible on multiple devices via iCloud?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH1-SW1

Comment: Go with Core Data. That's the proper approach.